# How can this YUV420 video have uneven dimensions

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, vp9

Just trying to cement my understanding of video codecs and can't seem to find any information about this.

https://www.mediafire.com/file/cbx8sciq5mie94m/arrow.webm/file contains a tiny vp9 webm. This was generated by me via `ffmpeg` by doing a simple gif -> webm conversion.

The source gif had a `13x11` resolution. Somehow, the output video also has a `13x11` resolution. I'm trying to understand how that is possible.

As far as I understand:

1. The YUV420 pixel format would make this impossible due to the chroma subsampling factor of 2 forcing a divisibility by two requirement.
2. VP9 itself has a minimum block size of 16x16(?) so at least that much data must be encoded(?)

Consequently, it's my assumption we have either a ~14x12 or ~16x16 video stream encoded here that is being somehow scaled or cropped down to 13x11.

The problem is I can't find any explanation as to how this is working.

Here's the ffprobe output for the stream:

```
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=vp9
codec_long_name=Google VP9
profile=Profile 0
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/60
codec_tag_string=[0][0][0][0]
codec_tag=0x0000
width=13
height=11
coded_width=13
coded_height=11
closed_captions=0
has_b_frames=0
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
display_aspect_ratio=13:11
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=-99
color_range=tv
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=unspecified
field_order=unknown
timecode=N/A
refs=1
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=60/1
avg_frame_rate=60/1
time_base=1/1000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=N/A
duration=N/A
bit_rate=N/A
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=N/A
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
DISPOSITION:timed_thumbnails=0
TAG:alpha_mode=1
TAG:ENCODER=Lavc58.91.100 libvpx-vp9
TAG:DURATION=00:00:00.600000000
[/STREAM]
```

and for the last frame:

```
[FRAME]
media_type=video
stream_index=0
key_frame=0
pkt_pts=583
pkt_pts_time=0.583000
pkt_dts=583
pkt_dts_time=0.583000
best_effort_timestamp=583
best_effort_timestamp_time=0.583000
pkt_duration=16
pkt_duration_time=0.016000
pkt_pos=3639
pkt_size=15
width=13
height=11
pix_fmt=yuv420p
sample_aspect_ratio=1:1
pict_type=P
coded_picture_number=0
display_picture_number=0
interlaced_frame=0
top_field_first=0
repeat_pict=0
color_range=tv
color_space=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
chroma_location=unspecified
[/FRAME]
```

going off the `coded_width` and `coded_height` values (supposed to represent the "true" width/height before any scaling(?)) plus `sar` value of 1, as far as I can tell this is genuinely a 13x11 video stream, but that should be impossible no?

My question is, why is this a valid video file?

If I try to e.g. `zscale` something to an uneven resolution in `YUV420` pixel format I hit the expected chroma subsampling errors.

Comment: You are right that chroma (UV planes) needs even number of pixels. For situations like that codec likely to add padding along the edges filled with zeroes (or whatever suitable) so to encode that properly. Player is cutting off that padding because it has width/height information.

Comment: @user3124812 but wouldn't I expect the `coded_width` / `coded_height` to reflect the true width/height of the video stream if it were padded? Can I just encode videos with whatever amount of padding I want and override width/height metadata somehow?

Comment: I have not deal with VP9, but I would not expect that codec would give you what it does under the hood. You could override width/height of raw video by adding paddings, but after that you would need to encode a whole lot again. Something about 'resize video' should give the idea.

Comment: Is there some command I can run to e.g. pad a video with black pixels and then "hide" those padding pixels by lying about the width/height of the video? I can't find anything like that supported in `ffmpeg`?

I'm trying to understand what's happening to make this a valid video by recreating it but there seems to be no way to encode this 

if I replace the `scale=13:11` with `zscale=13:11` it actually complains for the chroma issue. So `scale` is doing "something" to make this work. I just don't know what.